# Separating OpenGL dependency from client code and server code

Tags: c++, opengl, dependencies

In a game I'm writing, I'd like to have a dedicated server connect to a client with OpenGL rendering.  Everything is looking great, except that the server has an unfortunate dependency on mesa/OpenGL.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a dedicated server without having to install anything on top of a tenminal.

Basically, it boils down to this.  Each of my game objects have a sprite.  In order to render this sprite, the image data must be sent to the graphics card via `glTexImage2D`, and a `GLuint` is associated with the texture data.  To render a texture, you need the texture id.

I'm separating client from server by using two different main files, which share the same core game files. Only the client `#include`'s graphics-related files.  My overall class structure looks like this:

```
//Core game stuff
class Image
{
    int width, height;
    //Image data
}

class Sprite
{
    const Image image;
}

//Graphics namespace
void renderObject()
{
    //Some rendering code...

    GLuint texId = loadTexture(someSprite.image);

    renderTexture(texId);

    unloadTexture(texId);
}
```

Now, this looks great, until we realize that sending the image data to the graphics card every frame is *slow* and needs to be cached.  It would make sense to store the `GLuint` on the image, and even give it a `getTexture()` function.  If not set, the function would load the texture and return the id.  Thus, the image data would only be sent to the graphics card once.

```
//Core game stuff
class Image
{
    int width, height;
    //Image data

    GLuint textureId;

  public:

    ~Image()
    {
        //...

        unloadTexture(textureId);
    }

    GLuint getTexture()
    {
        if(!textureId)
            return textureId = loadTexture();
        else
            return textureId;
    }
}

class Sprite
{
    const Image image;
}

//Graphics namespace
void renderObject()
{
    //Some rendering code...

    renderTexture(someSprite.image.getTexture());  //loadTexture() is only called once
}
```

However, due to using `gl*` functions and a `#include <GL/gl.h>` this makes `Image` dependent on OpenGL, which makes all of my game objects dependent on OpenGL.  At this point, the server version of my code (without the OpenGL context or rendering) is dependent on OpenGL.

How do you suggest I go about solving this?  A `#ifdef CLIENT` would be one solution, though I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your post as asking for (1) minimal changes to your code above and (2) not using any preprocessor constructs.

As you disallow compile time differentiation (e.g. using #ifdef), the solution will most likely boil down to the client setting some datum at runtime to change the execution path. The most direct manifestation of this idea would be global function pointers:

```
unsigned int (*loadTexturePtr)(int width, int height, void *pixels) = NULL; 
void (*unloadTexturePtr)(unsigned int texId) = NULL;
```

The client initialization code sets them to point to the GL dependent implementations. Your Image code is nearly unchanged:

```
class Image
{
unsigned int textureId;
public:
~Image() 
{
  if (textureId && unloadTexturePtr) unloadTexturePtr(textureId);
}
unsigned int getTexture()
{
  if(!textureId && loadTexturePtr) textureId = loadTexturePtr(...);
  return textureId;
}
...
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that, not a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

You would go about solving this by *abandoning* your entire client/server architecture and doing it right.

The servers has *no need* to know *anything* at all about OpenGL. It doens't need to know about "sprites" or "images". It doesn't even need to know what a particular client should *draw*. All the server needs to do is maintain the state of the world, farm that state out to the various clients, and update that state based on the inputs those clients provide.

If your server even *loads* "images" and "sprites", you're doing client/server wrong. All it should load is whatever physical and collision properties these objects have. It's up to each individual client to load the "images" and so forth.

Your server should not be using OpenGL at all.

Comment: OpenGL has no image loading capabilities.

Comment: In a highly dynamic world, and in my game in particular, the client doesn't know about all the possible textures and sprites that could be in the game.  The server _sends_ the client this info.

Comment: @roadkillguy: First, if that's true, you should have listed that as being necessary for the functionality of your server in your question. Most client/server architectures don't need that, no matter how "highly dynamic" their worlds are, so it's something you should have stated up-front. Second, as you pointed out, sending images to the client still doesn't involve *OpenGL*, which is what you asked about. So your problem still seems to be poor code architecture: your server's "Image" object has no business storing an OpenGL texture object.

Comment: No, no it doesn't.  How else might I go about associating a texture object with an image?  I don't want textures to fill up on the graphics card when their associated images have been destroyed.

Comment: @roadkillguy: There aren't too many ways I can says this; the last line in the post explains it as clearly as I can. If your server is using OpenGL *at all* (at least for rendering), you're doing it wrong. You don't need to associate a texture object with an image because your server doesn't have texture objects. Your server should load images and farm them out to clients as needed. Your server can tell those clients when to delete them. It's up to the clients to put them in textures and delete them when they're told to.

Comment: Ok, ok, I know.  I always knew.  No need to tell me that any more.  How does the *client* go about making this association?

Comment: Perhaps a GUID? Could your server stamp a particular texture data (image) with a GUID when it farms it out? Then when it's deleted the server transmits the GUID of the image to be destroyed? On the client side you glDeleteTextures() the tex_id associated with that GUID.

Comment: The server wouldn't be telling them when to destroy the images, that's silly.  Completely on the client side, now that we've established that the `GLuid` cannot be stored on the `Image` class, how do we tell when to free the texture object?  Somehow we have to know when the image is destroyed, so we can call `glDeleteTextures()`.

Comment: @roadkillguy: "*The server wouldn't be telling them when to destroy the images, that's silly.*" If the server tells the client to allocate the images (by uploading them), then that means the server is the one who controls their lifetimes. It's the server that knows when the server is finished with that image. And therefore it is the server who must have the responsibility of telling clients to destroy those images.

Comment: Is this some kind of misplaced c pointer ownership guideline?  My current image transfer design works based on resourceID's and resource requests.  The idea that `free()` would ever be called across a network makes no sense to me.  Anyway, I accepted an answer.